# Run a docker container over 2 physical computers

Tags: docker, central-processing-unit

It is possible with docker cli to limit the number of CPUs for running container (--cpus option)?

It it possible to change this limit when the container is running? Or should I delete the container and re-create it?

Let's suppose I have 2 physical computers with 4 CPUs.

How can I run a docker container on 8 CPUs? What I want to do is to make work the 2 physical computers for a unique docker container (2x4 CPUs).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It it possible to change this limit when the container is running ? Or should i delete the container et re-create it ?

Re-create it.

> How can i run a docker container on 8 cpus ? What i want to do is to make work the 2 physical computers for a unique docker container (2x4 cpus)

You can't. Docker is ***not*** a clustering technology.